# Accessing a CentOS 7 (minimal) server running on VirtualBox from outside

Tags: apache, centos, server

Is it possible to access my Apache server from outside the VirtualBox on Google Chrome browser? Its running on CentOS 7 on VirtualBox. 
I have tried connecting to the ip address of the CentOS virtual machine but it didn't work. Its using 'Bridged Adapter' networking in the VM settings and i checked the ip address using the 'ip addr' command. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Though you need to add a *tunnel* to allow access to your Centos 7 machine web service from the host machine.

For example, my VM's bridge IP address (the interface that connects to the world) is **192.168.1.38** and its interface is **enp0s3**. Let's say I'm running the web service on my second interface, **enp0s8** with IP **192.168.100.101** on port **8000**. Here's how you create the tunnel:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i enp0s3 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.101:8000
services iptables save
```

That's it. You should be able to go to your **host's** Chrome browser and type in the url **192.168.1.38** and be presented with your web service. If it's still not working I'd suggest looking into your iptables rules to see if any is blocking this traffic.

Comment: I am facing the same problem and try iptables command as you mentioned however it didn't worked for me, i have nginx on centos 7 guest machine and trying to access for ubuntu host.however i am able to ssh into guest. i have set two networks for my vm "NAT" and "Host-only-adapter".
On enp0s3: inet is 10.0.2.15 and enp0s8: inet is 192.168.56.101.
so i have run the command:  `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i enps03 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.56.101:8000
services iptables save`