# Can't access SVN on CentOS 7 VM in VirtualBox

Tags: centos, virtualbox, centos7

I installed VirtualBox on Windows 7, and created a virtual machine, where I installed CentOS 7. Then in CentOS 7 I installed CollabNet Subversion Edge, following [this information](http://binpipe.blogspot.com.ar/2012/04/installing-collabnet-svn-on-centos.html) as a guide and
performed all the steps provided there, but I can not access the server.

The installation should be performed on a desktop machine and the server I'm trying to access from a notebook, which is connected to the same network as the desktop machine. Also obviously, as the network has a proxy to surf, I had to configure it, and doing well because I can surf the internet and others. It's using 'Bridged Adapter' networking in the VM settings.

Can you think of any idea why I do not have access? Any help is welcome.

I found [a response similar to what I'm looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003677/accessing-a-centos-7-minimal-server-running-on-virtualbox-from-outside), but do not quite understand what it says. I'm only in CentOS7 enp0s3 interface, and there is collabnet running, not running on another interface.

NEWS:Gain access the server using its IP (172.x.x.x:3343/svn or 172.x.x.x:18080/svn), but not by name. Maybe there is a problem in the computer name, applies only to Windows, and CentOS running on the virtual machine, use another computer name. Can it be? If so, you know how to identify such equipment?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a firewall issue. Try to run following commands:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=<dst_port>/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Hope this helps

Comment: dst_port port would I use to access CollabNet? (I was 80, and modify it to 18080, you should use dst_port = 18080?)

Comment: yes. dst_port is a port on which your server is accepting connections. If it was 80 and switched to 18080 - your dst_port will become also 18080

Comment: iwlagn thanks for your help, but I still can't access.

Comment: @FabrizioGelsi - can you access it from localhost? Do you have "connection refused" or "not found/internal server error/other possible HTTP error"?

Comment: Exactly, since centos7, I can access it via localhost:3343/csvn/ and have the svn "Racing".

Comment: On windows7, when I try acces, the error it is: "Can not connect

Firefox can not establish a connection to the server ------------."

Comment: if you access svn via port 3343 - you should also enable it in your firewall to access it from windows machine

Comment: Gain access the server using its IP (172.x.x.x:3343/svn or 172.x.x.x:18080/svn), but not by name. Maybe there is a problem in the computer name, applies only to Windows, and CentOS running on the virtual machine, use another computer name. Can it be? If so, you know how to identify such equipment?

Comment: do you have dns configured to access your VM via it's name?

Comment: Yes, I have... :/. They are configured automatically when you enable network in centos. DNS I have put in windows loaded.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Do you have separate DNS server installed, that knows IP of your CentOS box and can provide it to your Windows box?